# VPN for specific addresses

Tags: vpn

Right now I have to connect to 2 separate corporate VPNs using different, proprietary VPN software for ssh/http/smb services. I can't use them at the same time and they take over my whole computer (slowing down downloads, etc). Is there a way I can set up an individual computer (Mac/Ubuntu) or a LAN so that I don't have to do this? I would like to be able to do "ssh hostname@server4.companyX.com" and it automatically connects the VPN - only routing that ssh session through it. The same for connecting an SMB share.

I can vaguely imagine a lot of solutions, but I don't really know where to start looking. I can vaguely imagine setting up a raspberry pi/VM running the different VPN clients that passes along any traffic.

Comment: Have you considered using virtual machines? I do this and use a different virtual machine for each company and connecting to each VPN.

Comment: Does any of them force a default route on to your machine, or does the networks conflicts (same subnets on both ends)
It could be possible to do specific routes, or even some firewalling NAT mangling to get it working, but more data from `ip r` when each of them are connected would probably be needed, but could contain some sensitive information.